# Salesforce - user trigger not invoked when user role changes

Tags: trigger, user, role-hierarchy

There are two ways to change user role. One is from user detail page, which invoke user trigger.
I am facing issue where if user role is changed from ROLE hierarchy screen, then user trigger is not being invoked.

Any body know if there is written documentation which specifies this? or is it just my ORG having some setting to skip user trigger?

Below is screenshot of the screen from where it happens.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [Known Issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000Re2cAAC). This is not the first time something like this has happened. A few special "standard features" happen to ignore triggers. This feature is In Review, so it may actually get fixed some day. By using the "This Issue Affects Me" button, you'll be notified when this is fixed.