# Why does assigning a role from the role hierarchy page bypass validation rules?

Tags: validation-rule, roles

I set up a validation rule that prevents our delegated admin users from creating/updating a user to not have a role. The validation rule works exactly as expected when creating/updating the user directly from a user record.

```
AND( 
ISPICKVAL(UserType, "Standard"), 
ISBLANK(UserRoleId))
```

Today, I found that some of our delegated users have inadvertently removed roles from some of our users via the Setup | Manage Users | Roles | and then using the assign link by removing the user from the list.

[image]

Why does this area ignore validation rules and is there a non-programmatic way to enforce removing a role from a user?

Comment: Seems to be a known issue. As explained by @sfdcfox here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/205181/salesforce-user-trigger-not-invoked-when-user-role-changes/205186#205186

Comment: I'll take that as an acceptable answer. As far as handling this, looks like we'll go the old school route of audit reports, education, and hand slapping - which is not a great experience for the end users who suddenly find they no longer have access to records. Not a great way to surprise folks at the end of the year!

Comment: Make sure you sign up for that Known Issue so you can notified of resolution.